# How can I lock a guest user into a game environment?

Tags: windows-10, gaming, kiosk, lock, nvidia-gamestream

Basically I'm looking to share my gaming PC with a friend but only in a way that would let him play my games without accessing any of my other files, parts of my OS / desktop environment

Windows 10 Pro

No browsing the internet, no nothing, just letting him launch games and exit them.

Comment: Windows does not have anything that would remotely be close to what you describe

Comment: Remove the old SSD or HDD, put a new HDD or SSD in the PC, install Windows 10, uninstall any apps you want to prevent him using. When he's done, reinstall old SSD/HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged nVidia Gamestream, if you have a launcher for the games you want your friend to have access to, you could think about replacing the Windows shell (sort of the desktop environment) with the Gamestream Client.

To turn on Shell Launcher in Windows features

- Go to Control Panel > Programs and features > Turn Windows features
  on or off.
- Expand Device Lockdown.
- Select Shell Launcher and OK.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher

Please be aware that this is not 100%. It doesn't block access to files, it only makes it harder for them to get to. For example, if a game or the launcher has an "open files" dialog, your friend would still be able to access your files, etc. Something that's even 100% close to blocking access to resources like this is impossible on Windows or would require a great deal of configuration with Group Policies.